# AVAudioPlayer won't work

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have a question. The following code could not manage to play anything. And there are no errors according to the compiler. I have made the necessary connections. In fact instead of `AVAudioPlayer`, if I use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`, everything works.I would be glad if someone can help me.Because I need to use the AVAudioPlayer for my project and I have tried everything that I know.

Thanks

**.h file**

```cs
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@property(strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

- (IBAction)cal:(id)sender;
```

**.m file**

```cs
- (IBAction)cal:(id)sender {

    NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath : path];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:pathURL error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,after hours of trying I managed to solve the issue.It is hard to believe but what I did was
to rename(no conversion) the mp3 file to m4a and change the corresponding code in the source to m4a.That was it...